# A case where abstract and static would be usefull. How can I solve it?

Tags: java, abstract-class, static-methods

I would like to have an abstract helper class where I instantiate the classes that I need in my helper-sub-classes. In the abstract class there is a method that is common to all sub-classes but it has a slight difference specific to each sub-class and therefore must be ad-hoc implemented.
As, generally, an helper-class only has static methods what it would be nice to have is an abstract static method so that it must be present/implemented in all sub-classes and it can be called as an helper-method. But as we all know this is not possible...

Here my concrete example:

```
public abstract class ClientHelper
{
  protected static A a= new A();
  protected static B b= new B();
  ...

  abstract static public String getX( String id );
}

public static class UserType1ClientHelper extends ClientHelper
{
  @Override
  public String getX( String id )
  {
    return a.getX(id, SPECIFIC_PARAMETER_FOR_USERTYPE1)
  }
  ...
}

public static class UserType2ClientHelper extends ClientHelper
{
  @Override
  public String getX( String id )
  {
    return b.getX(id, SPECIFIC_PARAMETER_FOR_USERTYPE2)
  }
  ...
}
```

How can I reproduce this in a "possible" way?

Comment: Just don't use static. Dependency injection can help you distribute the reference to your helper object. Though in this case I would question the need for multiple helper classes in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the base class needs to know classes A and B, you might do:

```
enum ClientHelper {
    USER_TYPE_1(new A()),
    USER_TYPE_2(new B());

    private ClientHelper(... obj) {
    }

    public String getX(String id) {
        ...
    }

}
```

and/or

```
enum ClientHelper {
    USER_TYPE_1() {
        A a = new A();

        @Override
        public String getX(String id) {
             ...
        }
    },
    USER_TYPE_2() {
        ...
    };

    public abstract String getX(String id);

}

String x = ClientHelper.USER_TYPE2.getX("H");
```

The latter is more verbose, but allows more variance.

It uses that every enum value is a static instance.

Answer (score 1):

> As, generally, an helper-class only has static methods what it would
>   be nice to have is an abstract static method

Helper class having static method is fine, but if you don't have implementation for it, how that method is going to be useful being present in Helper class as `abstract` method.

I understand, you like to call that method for all derived classes by using your `ClientHelper` type reference. Since the method is abstract, and derived class has to provide implementation for it, make it `non-static` i.e. remove static and use it as instance method.

Comment: But then I have to instantiate the class... My main concern is not to call that method for all derived classes by using `ClientHelper` but  to force all the sub-classes to implement the method and having it at disposal without to instantiate the sub-class.

Comment: @Francesco What is wrong with instantiating a class?

Comment: @biziclop Is not wrong, but I would like to have an helper class and normally they have only `public` `static` methods...